# Is it possible to handle dom events of an elements which are resides in iframe on parent page?

Tags: javascript, jquery, iframe

I know that some questions are already asked related to iframe elements and jquery. In my case I am including an iframe on lets say sample.php. My iframe contains "Select" Element with number of options in it. 
Now what I want to perform is that When changing the options from dropdown in iframe I want to handle that change event on my sample.php. Is it possible?

If so please help

Thanks

Comment: Please show us what you've tried already (ie - show us some code!)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this,

```js
window.frames['myIFrame'].document.getElementById('selectElement').onChange = function() {

}
```

Comment: Thanks Syms, I tried exactly and it worked! Thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

maybe [window.postMessage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/postMessage) is also a solution for you

```
otherWindow.postMessage(message, targetOrigin, [transfer]);
```